# I am not able to create ionic2 project

Tags: html

I am trying to create an ionic2 project, using command

```
ionic start ProjectName blank --type=v2 --ts
```

but I get this error.

> [ERROR] Unable to find starter type for --v2.

How can I create ionic2 project with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`ionic start ProjectName blank --v2 --ts`

instead of

`ionic start ProjectName blank --type=v2 --ts`